# Como manter só linhas específicas do DataFrame?

Tags: r, webforms, tabela-html, data.frame, web-scraping

Tenho um código que entra em um site, preenche um form e puxa uma tabela, entretanto, eu quero excluir algumas linhas dessa tabela que não preciso.

Vamos ao código:

```
#library's
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
require(stringr)
require(plyr)
require(rvest)
require(xlsx)

#previa
info <- debugGatherer()
handle <- getCurlHandle(cookiejar = "",
followlocation = TRUE,
autoreferer = TRUE,
debugfunc = info$update,
verbose = TRUE,
httpheader = list(
from = "eddie@r-datacollection.com",
'user-agent' = str_c(R.version$version.string,
", ", R.version$platform)
))


xmlAttrsToDF <- function(parsedHTML, xpath) {
x <- xpathApply(parsedHTML, xpath, xmlAttrs)
x <- lapply(x, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))
do.call(rbind.fill, x)
}

#website
url <- "http://www.ceagesp.gov.br/entrepostos/servicos/cotacoes/"
html_form <- getURL(url, curl = handle)
parsed_form <- htmlParse(html_form)
pgsession <-html_session(url)              
pgform    <-html_form(pgsession)[[3]] 

xmlAttrsToDF(parsed_form, "//form")


######LEGUMES######
res2 <- postForm(uri = str_c(url, "#cotacao"),
curl = handle,
style = "POST",
"cot_grupo" = "legumes",
"cot_data" = "06/03/2017")
legumes <- readHTMLTable(res2)
legumes <- data.frame(legumes)
legumes <- subset(legumes, select = c(NULL.V1, NULL.V2, NULL.V5, NULL.V7))
```

Ele me gera essa tabela quando eu digito `legumes`:

```
              NULL.V1       NULL.V2 NULL.V5 NULL.V7
1                  Produto Classificação   Comun   Quilo
2         ABOBORA JAPONESA             -    1,54       1
3             ABOBORA SECA             -    1,46       1
4          ABOBORA MORANGA             -    1,21       1
5         ABOBORA PAULISTA             -    1,49       1
6     ABOBRINHA BRASILEIRA      EXTRA AA    2,25       1
7     ABOBRINHA BRASILEIRA       EXTRA A    1,97       1
8     ABOBRINHA BRASILEIRA         EXTRA     1,5       1
9       ABOBRINHA ITALIANA      EXTRA AA     2,8       1
10      ABOBRINHA ITALIANA       EXTRA A    2,39       1
11      ABOBRINHA ITALIANA         EXTRA    1,82       1
12     BATATA DOCE AMARELA      EXTRA AA    3,11       1
13     BATATA DOCE AMARELA       EXTRA A    2,66       1
14     BATATA DOCE AMARELA         EXTRA    2,17       1
15      BATATA DOCE ROSADA      EXTRA AA    1,86       1
16      BATATA DOCE ROSADA       EXTRA A    1,66       1
17      BATATA DOCE ROSADA         EXTRA     1,4       1
18      BERINJELA CONSERVA         EXTRA     4,5       1
19      BERINJELA CONSERVA      ESPECIAL     3,5       1
20      BERINJELA CONSERVA      PRIMEIRA     2,5       1
21      BERINJELA JAPONESA         EXTRA    3,64       1
22      BERINJELA JAPONESA      ESPECIAL    3,03       1
23      BERINJELA JAPONESA      PRIMEIRA    2,34       1
24               BERINJELA      EXTRA AA    1,88       1
25               BERINJELA       EXTRA A    1,55       1
26               BERINJELA         EXTRA     1,2       1
27               BETERRABA      EXTRA AA    1,82       1
28               BETERRABA       EXTRA A     1,6       1
29               BETERRABA         EXTRA    1,33       1
30                    CARA       EXTRA A    3,21       1
31                    CARA         EXTRA    2,63       1
32                 CENOURA      EXTRA AA    2,11       1
33                 CENOURA       EXTRA A    1,81       1
34                 CENOURA         EXTRA    1,55       1
35                  CHUCHU      EXTRA AA    1,78       1
36                  CHUCHU       EXTRA A    1,55       1
37                  CHUCHU         EXTRA    1,23       1
38           ERVILHA TORTA      EXTRA AA   20,49       1
39           ERVILHA TORTA       EXTRA A   15,24       1
40           ERVILHA TORTA         EXTRA   11,55       1
41      TOMATE SWEET GRAPE      EXTRA AA    9,16       1
42                GENGIBRE             -    3,26       1
43                  INHAME       EXTRA A     3,4       1
44                  INHAME         EXTRA    2,86       1
45                  INHAME      ESPECIAL    2,33       1
46            JILO REDONDO      EXTRA AA    2,27       1
47            JILO REDONDO       EXTRA A    1,85       1
48            JILO REDONDO         EXTRA    1,46       1
49                MANDIOCA        GRAUDA    2,11       1
50                MANDIOCA         MEDIA    1,83       1
51                MANDIOCA         MIUDA    1,54       1
52            MANDIOQUINHA     EXTRA AAA    4,21       1
53            MANDIOQUINHA      EXTRA AA    3,49       1
54            MANDIOQUINHA       EXTRA A    2,81       1
55                  MAXIXE             -    3,06       1
56          PEPINO CAIPIRA      EXTRA AA    1,86       1
57          PEPINO CAIPIRA       EXTRA A    1,57       1
58          PEPINO CAIPIRA         EXTRA    1,28       1
59            PEPINO COMUM      EXTRA AA     1,9       1
60            PEPINO COMUM       EXTRA A    1,54       1
61            PEPINO COMUM         EXTRA    1,24       1
62          PEPINO JAPONES      EXTRA AA    2,69       1
63          PEPINO JAPONES       EXTRA A    2,23       1
64          PEPINO JAPONES         EXTRA    1,82       1
65      PIMENTA * VERMELHA      EXTRA AA     3,8       1
66      PIMENTA * VERMELHA       EXTRA A     3,2       1
67         PIMENTA CAMBUCI      EXTRA AA    3,48       1
68         PIMENTA CAMBUCI       EXTRA A    2,83       1
69 PIMENTA VERDE AMERICANA      EXTRA AA    3,27       1
70 PIMENTA VERDE AMERICANA       EXTRA A    2,82       1
71 PIMENTA VERDE AMERICANA         EXTRA    2,34       1
72          PIMENTAO VERDE      EXTRA AA    2,71       1
73          PIMENTAO VERDE       EXTRA A    2,17       1
74          PIMENTAO VERDE         EXTRA    1,73       1
75       PIMENTAO VERMELHO      EXTRA AA    3,33       1
76       PIMENTAO VERMELHO       EXTRA A    2,81       1
77       PIMENTAO VERMELHO         EXTRA    2,27       1
78        PIMENTAO AMARELO      EXTRA AA    2,65       1
79             QUIABO LISO      EXTRA AA    4,25       1
80             QUIABO LISO       EXTRA A     3,7       1
81             QUIABO LISO         EXTRA    3,17       1
82         TOMATE ITALIANO     EXTRA AAA     3,2       1
83         TOMATE ITALIANO      EXTRA AA    2,57       1
84         TOMATE ITALIANO       EXTRA A    2,01       1
85  TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND     EXTRA AAA    3,05       1
86  TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND      EXTRA AA     2,5       1
87  TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND       EXTRA A       2       1
88          TOMATE OBLONGO     EXTRA AAA    2,99       1
89          TOMATE OBLONGO      EXTRA AA    2,45       1
90          TOMATE OBLONGO       EXTRA A    1,82       1
91            TOMATE CAQUI      EXTRA AA    8,09       1
92           TOMATE CEREJA      EXTRA AA    5,71       1
93    VAGEM MACARRAO CURTA      EXTRA AA    5,07       1
94    VAGEM MACARRAO CURTA       EXTRA A    3,97       1
95    VAGEM MACARRAO CURTA         EXTRA    3,13       1
96          VAGEM MANTEIGA      EXTRA AA     4,4       1
97          VAGEM MANTEIGA       EXTRA A     3,8       1
98          VAGEM MANTEIGA         EXTRA     3,2       1
```

Entretanto eu quero somente 2 itens dessa tabela (excluindo o resto, pois pretendo passar pro Excel), e desejo selecioná-los pelo nome, pois às vezes essa tabela vem desordenada.

Eu gostaria de selecionar os produtos MANDIOCA e TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND, com classificações MEDIA e EXTRA A, respectivamente.

É isso, se alguém tiver uma ideia de como deixar meu código mais limpo eu agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, eu faria uma pequena limpeza no teu conjunto de dados `legumes`. Note que o cabeçalho não tem nomes com significado intuitivo e a primeira linha dele possui algo que poderia substituir este cabeçalho:

```
head(legumes)
               NULL.V1       NULL.V2 NULL.V5 NULL.V7
1              Produto Classificação   Comun   Quilo
2     ABOBORA JAPONESA             -    1,54       1
3         ABOBORA SECA             -    1,46       1
4      ABOBORA MORANGA             -    1,21       1
5     ABOBORA PAULISTA             -    1,49       1
6 ABOBRINHA BRASILEIRA      EXTRA AA    2,25       1
```

Os dois comandos abaixo resolvem este problema:

```
names(legumes) <- as.character(unlist(legumes[1, ]))
legumes <- legumes[-1, ]
head(legumes)
               Produto Classificação Comun Quilo
2     ABOBORA JAPONESA             -  1,54     1
3         ABOBORA SECA             -  1,46     1
4      ABOBORA MORANGA             -  1,21     1
5     ABOBORA PAULISTA             -  1,49     1
6 ABOBRINHA BRASILEIRA      EXTRA AA  2,25     1
7 ABOBRINHA BRASILEIRA       EXTRA A  1,97     1
```

O fato da primeira linha agora ser identificada com o número 2 não é um problema neste caso.

Com o data frame ajeitado, basta usar o comando `filter` do pacote `dplyr` para atingir o resultado desejado, isto é, selecionar as linhas com os produtos MANDIOCA e TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND, com classificações MEDIA e EXTRA A, respectivamente.

```
library(dplyr)

filter(legumes, (Produto=="MANDIOCA" & Classificação=="MEDIA") |
  (Produto=="TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND" & Classificação=="EXTRA A"))
                 Produto Classificação Comun Quilo
1               MANDIOCA         MEDIA  1,83     1
2 TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND       EXTRA A     2     1
```

Comment: Marcus, sua solução me serviu bastante. Muito legal esse negócio de substituir o nome das colunas, não tinha ideia. Quanto a Mandioca, o média é uma classificação do produto, talvez por isso tenha dado errado. Mas ainda assim, testei aqui e não consegui selecionar só as linhas que quero, que são essas:
MANDIOCA         MEDIA  1,83     1
TOMATE ACHATADO-REDOND       EXTRA A     2     1

Comment: Não era esta a pergunta no post original. Entretanto, editei o código para refletir esta mudança.

Comment: Saquei, precisa ter o OU e o E funcionando ao mesmo tempo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Marcus, você tem alguma sugestão em de que maneira eu posso "automatizar" a data a ser buscada? Eu gostaria de colocar sempre a data de um dia antes. Por exemplo, hoje é dia 08, eu gostaria que buscasse do dia 07.

Comment: Infelizmente não. Abra uma nova pergunta para atrair mais atenção a esta dúvida. Talvez outras pessoas saibam respondê-la.